# Select that splits rows with range into several rows with smaller ranges?

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables that contain categorized tsrange values. The ranges in each table are non-overlapping per category, but the ranges in `b` might overlap those in `a`.

```
create table a ( id serial primary key, category int, period tsrange );
create table b ( id serial primary key, category int, period tsrange );
```

What I would like to do is combine these two tables into a CTE for another query. The combined values needs to be the tsranges from table `a` **subtracted by** any overlapping tsranges in table `b` with the same category.

The complication is that in the case where an overlapping `b.period` is contained inside an `a.period`, the result of the subtraction is two rows. The Postgres Range `-` operator does not support this, so I create a function that will return 1 or 2 rows:

```
create function subtract_tsrange( a tsrange , b tsrange )
returns table (period tsrange)
language 'plpgsql' as $$
begin
    if a @> b and not isempty(b) and lower(a) <> lower(b) and upper(b) <> upper(a)
    then
        period := tsrange(lower(a), lower(b), '[)');
        return next;
        period := tsrange(upper(b), upper(a), '[)');
        return next;
    else
        period :=  a - b;
        return next;
    end if;
    return;
end
$$;
```

There can also be several `b.period`s overlapping an `a.period`, so one row from `a` might be potentially be split into a lot of rows with shorter periods.

Now I want to create a select that takes each row in `a` and returns:

- The original `a.period` if there is no overlapping `b.period` with the same category

or

- 1 or several rows representing the original `a.period` minus all overlapping `b.period`s with the same category.

After reading lots of other posts I figure I should use SELECT LATERAL in combination with my function somehow, but I'm still scratching my head as to how?? (We're talking Postgres 9.6 btw!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Notes**: your problem can easily be generalized to every range types, therefore I will use the `anyrange` pseudo type in my answer, but you don't have to. In fact because of this I had to create a generic constructor for range types, because PostgreSQL have not defined it (yet):

```
create or replace function to_range(t anyrange, l anyelement, u anyelement, s text default '[)', out to_range anyrange)
language plpgsql as $func$
begin
  execute format('select %I($1, $2, $3)', pg_typeof(t)) into to_range using l, u, s;
end
$func$;
```

Of course, you can use the appropriate range constructor instead of `to_range()` calls.

Also, I will use the `numrange` type for testing purposes, as it can be created and checked more easily than the `tsrange` type, but my answer should work with that as well.

**Answer**:

I rewrote your function to handle any type of bounds (inclusive, exclusive and even unbounded ranges). Also, it will return an empty result set when `a <@ b`.

```
create or replace function range_div(a anyrange, b anyrange)
returns setof anyrange
language sql as $func$
  select * from unnest(case
    when b is null or a <@ b then '{}'
    when a @> b then array[
      to_range(a, case when lower_inf(a) then null else lower(a) end,
                  case when lower_inf(b) then null else lower(b) end,
                  case when lower_inc(a) then '[' else '(' end ||
                  case when lower_inc(b) then ')' else ']' end),
      to_range(a, case when upper_inf(b) then null else upper(b) end,
                  case when upper_inf(a) then null else upper(a) end,
                  case when upper_inc(b) then '(' else '[' end ||
                  case when upper_inc(a) then ']' else ')' end)
    ]
    else array[a - b]
  end)
$func$;
```

With this in mind, what you need is somewhat an inverse of aggregation. F.ex. with `sum()` one can start with an empty value (`0`) and constantly add *some* value to that. But you have your *initial* value and you need to constantly remove *some* parts of it.

One solution to that is to use [recursive CTEs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html):

```
with recursive r as (
    select    *
    from      a
  union
    select     r.id, r.category, d
    from       r
    left join  b using (category)
    cross join range_div(r.period, b.period) d -- this is in fact an implicit lateral join
    where      r.period && b.period
)
select    r.*
from      r
left join b on r.category = b.category and r.period && b.period
where     not isempty(r.period) and b.period is null
```

My sample data:

```
create table a (id serial primary key, category int, period numrange);
create table b (id serial primary key, category int, period numrange);
insert into a (category, period) values (1, '[1,4]'), (1, '[2,5]'), (1, '[3,6]'), (2, '(1,6)');
insert into b (category, period) values (1, '[2,3)'), (1, '[1,2]'), (2, '[3,3]');
```

The query above produces:

```
id | category | period
 3 |  1       |  [3,6]
 1 |  1       |  [3,4]
 2 |  1       |  [3,5]
 4 |  2       |  (1,3)
 4 |  2       |  (3,6)
```

Comment: Great with a generalized answer! First question as I start to digest this: What is the unnest('{}') case in range_div()? I don't understand what that means (I am assuming it is not a typo since you seem to have actually run this code)

Comment: @JesperWe `'{}'` is an empty array (actually, it is an `unknown` typed literal, but its type will be coerced to the appropriate range's array type -- but that's hard to express with [PostgreSQL's generic-type system](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-pseudo.html), so I used the unknown literal instead). [`unnest(anyarray)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html) is set-returning function, which just simply results all it's elements one-by-one (but in a result-set instead of in an array).

Comment: I like this solution, I find it pretty neat. It works, too!